# Cocoa title bar issue

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my application, I am using `-setStyleMask` to change the style.

I am using `NSTitledWindowMask` flag to show/hide title bar.

The problem which I faced is that when I hide the title bar of window and made it visible it again by setting this in style mask, title of window is now no longer present in the title bar.

Means title on window before hiding title bar is not visible on window after making title bar visible.

Is there something I am missing or this is the expected behaviour in Cocoa.

Code:

```
void ShowTitlebar(bool pShowTitlebar)
{
        NSUInteger mask = [window styleMask];
    if(pShowTitlebar) {
        mask |= NSTitledWindowMask;
    } else {
        mask &= ~NSTitledWindowMask;
    }

    [window setStyleMask:mask];
}
```

Comment: showing your code would likely help.

Comment: @I'L'l: I have added the code. Problem is mentioned in the question.

Comment: I believe you have to sub-class NSWindow and override `canBecomeKeyWindow` for it to work.

Comment: @ParagBafna: Is there anything I am missing? It is showing/hiding title bar with no problem. Problem is that title before hidden is not visible after title bar is made visible.

Comment: @dbasic for me only window title is not visible.

Comment: That is my question and is the problem. Is there something wrong I am doing or is it an expected behaviour?

Comment: mask get lost as the function end, how can that function provide anything to happens? please post all relevant code

Comment: @Paolo Nice point out. I forget to put that statement. Now look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `setTitle` method after setting window StyleMask.

```
-(void) ShowTitlebar : (bool) pShowTitlebar
{
    NSUInteger mask = [self.window styleMask];
    NSLog(@"mask %lu",mask);
    if(pShowTitlebar) {
        mask |= NSTitledWindowMask;
    } else {
        mask &= ~NSTitledWindowMask;
    }
    [self.window setStyleMask:mask];
    [self.window setTitle:@"title"];

}
```

Comment: This is what I am already doing it. Is there any other way to retain title?

Comment: retain window title in instance variable  self.mytitle = self.window.title;